# Remove the opening and closing div inside WordPress content

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to remove a div added by a plugin to the content of WordPress posts. So the post has this structure:

```
<div class="post">
   <div class="some-class">
       <p>content</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to remove `<div class="some-class">` and its closing `</div>` but leave the content. So it would be:

```
<div class="post">
       <p>content</p>
</div>
```

using this filter:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'remove_class' , 100 );

function remove_class( $content ) {
            $content = preg_replace('#<div[^>]*class="some-class"[^>]*>.*?</div>#is', '', $content);
            return $content;
        }
```

the content is also deleted, I just want the div and the closing div to be deleted. Any idea how?

- this question is not duplicate of the other question because I want to remove a specific div not just all divs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove <div> tags from post contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40410711/how-to-remove-div-tags-from-post-contents)

Comment: @Gunaseelan this question is not duplicate of the other question because I want to remove a specific div not just all divs

Answer (score 2):

You could just try to remove class attribute, so that only `<div>` is left, using code like this:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'remove_class' , 100 );

function remove_class( $content ) {
            $content = preg_replace('/class=".*?"/', '', $content);
            return $content;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

@user7592255 you can try with jQuery like this:

```
$('p').unwrap();
```

If you can set an id or class on the p element you can target it more accurately

Answer (score 0):

The content is removed because you replace the entire matched string with an empty string. Use a [subpattern](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php) to capture the content of the `<div>` element and use it as replacement:

```
$content = preg_replace(
    '#<div[^>]*class="some-class"[^>]*>(.*?)</div>#is',
    '$1',
    $content
);
```

However, be aware that it won't work properly if the content of `<div class="some-class">` contains a `<div>` element.

There is no way to parse HTML using `regex`. The correct solution is to use an HTML parser ([`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) f.e.) to parse the HTML fragment and create its DOM, then operate the changes on the DOM and render it back to HTML.